# How do I Mock an Angular 2 route?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular2-routing, angular2-testing, angular2-router3

I have the following code...

```
export class LoginComponent {
    userName: string;
    password: string;
    rememberMe: boolean = false;
    constructor( private auth: AuthenticationService,
                 private router: Router) {
      ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I am trying to Unit test but my first attempt failed....

```
beforeEach(() => {
        router = new Router();
        component = new LoginComponent(authService, router);
});
```

Because it needs the params for the Router constructor. [Here I saw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35139882/angular-2-testing-components-with-router)...

```
beforeEach(() => addProviders([
    APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS, // must be first
    {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}, // must be second
    {provide: ActivatedRoute, useClass: Mock},
    {provide: Router, useClass: Mock}
]));
```

But I don't seem to have `APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS` or `Mock` anywhere in my dependencies, so I think it might be stale (or I need dependencies).

How do I mock this out? It doesn't even matter for the test I am working on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a simple case you could just create your own mock and provide it by value, for example:

```ts
describe('whatever', () => {
  let mockRouter: any;
  ...

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    // create your own mock 
    mockRouter = jasmine.createSpyObj('Router', ['navigate']);

    ...

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [LoginComponent],
      providers: [
        // provide it by value
        { provide: Router, useValue: mockRouter },
        ...
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  ...

});
```

This uses the test bed's dependency injection, rather than trying to "`new`-up" the class under test.

For an example in context, see e.g. [one of my projects on GitHub](https://github.com/textbook/known-for-web/blob/master/src/app/about/about.component.spec.ts).

Comment: How does this differ from the way that the actual project does it (I posted before I looked). It seems there we only need... `TestBed.configureTestingModule({imports: [RouterTestingModule]});` and `router = TestBed.get(Router);`? I haven't tested it yet though so I am not sure it works.

Comment: @Jackie What do you mean *"the actual project"*?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/router/test/router.spec.ts

Comment: @Jackie well they're testing the Router itself, you're testing *something that uses it*. Have you looked at the example I linked and tried this out?

Comment: I will try to look a little more and see if I get it. Sorry this stuff seems so esoteric to me. In my case I don't care about the side effects LOL but what I think you are saying is this does some extra stuff I don't need.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working example of loading query string parameters for each test. Works on Angular 2.3.

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        MyViewerComponent,
        ...
      ],
      imports: [
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule,
        ...  
      ],
      providers: [
        {provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: {queryParams: {test: 111}}},
        {provide: MyService, useClass: MyMockService}
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Answer (score 2):

I accepted the above answer because it appears to be correct, however, I actually implemented it differently...

```
describe("Login Component", () => {
    let component: LoginComponent;
    let authService: AuthenticationService;
    let router: Router;

    describe("Testing the subscription happens", () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({imports: [RouterTestingModule]});
            router = TestBed.get(Router);
            authService = new AuthenticationService();
            authService.notifications = new Subject();
            authService.notifications.subscribe = jasmine.createSpy("SpyToTestNotifications");
        });
        it("Make sure we try to subscribe to the auth event", () => {
            component = new LoginComponent(authService, router);
            expect(authService.notifications.subscribe).toHaveBeenCalled();
        })
    });
});
```

As you can see this only requires 2 lines in the beforeEach...

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({imports: [RouterTestingModule]});
router = TestBed.get(Router);
```

However, per @jonrsharpe this does a lot of things so you can't guarantee what other side effects might happen. But it is quick, it is dirty and it does seem to "work"